# Unsolvable NVIDIA & Ubuntu 16.x compatibility

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I probably tried every possible fixes and solutions given on the web for almost a year, trying all the possible differents configurations, OS versions, drivers versions etc.. No need to precise that I performed a clean install a hundred times.
This thread is about Nvidia issue but really I have a lot more -for the moment- unsolvable issues about the microphone not being recognized (bug followed on `launchpad` by lots of people, still in wait of a fix), fans working but not being recognized (same), incompatible `Nvidia drivers`... which makes me believe the issue is deeper than just a driver being incompatible with my laptop. But I don't have enough knowledge to understand what causes these issues.

- `lshw` : http://pastebin.com/fr04F9M7
- laptop : Acer VN7-792G
- graphics : Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) & NVidia GTX 960M - Optimus
- Current OS : Ubuntu 16.10 Gnome
- Kernel version : 4.8.0-30-generic (I tried differents versions, no results)

First, none of the graphics drivers provided by `ppa:graphic-drivers` work. (available in Software Center : `358.16/364.19/367.57/370.28`.- `340.98` is missing.).
Either they don't install correctly, either I get an error. 
When a driver finally installs for some reason, it's clearly not working as it shows 20FPS on 3D use. Even when one works with fluidity and high FPS, it eventually crashes.

The graphic driver recommended by `ppa:graphic-drivers` for my **960M** is the `340.98`, which does not install with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`. (login loop on gnome, black screen+low resolution on boot with error message on Unity. I tried all the solutions given online, none worked, apart from completly removing the driver).

I even tried the non-recommended method to download and install the driver from Nvidia's website. Followed all the [recommended steps by Nvidia](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/295.59/README/index.html) which eventually led me to an error that seems to have no solution

> Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'

I tried the ppa method on another laptop which has a **Nvidia 870M** with the recommended `340.98` that, this time, appears in the Software Center. Everything works like a charm.

Some recent -almost- similar threads are implying Kernel incompatibilities. I don't know more.

I know for sure that this particular laptop has a lot of trouble with Linux (or maybe just Ubuntu ?), but what is the cause ?

I tried to keep this thread as short and readable as possible, but I really tried a huge tons of "solutions". And as I feel to have tried everything I could, I come here for help. 
I can give any more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nvidia has now said that it will not support linux to the degree of Windows and Mac anymore. So there will be hoops to jump through, and stumbling blocks. What errors does it give when you try to install drivers available via the repo?

Comment: Ppa drivers show no errors, except from one about missing firmware for Kabylake, according to other threads it doesn't affect me so I can just ignore it. They just fail to work correctly (overheating, low fps, screen shatter, freezes/crashes, choose one). As for the recommended one 340.98 : with Unity it show a black screen with low resolution error before login screen, with Gnome it stucks at this screen during boot http://hpics.li/60fb76d . I understand Nvidia and Linux have issues, but why the driver 340.98 works on my other laptop (and appears in Software Center), but not on this laptop ?

Comment: If it is the exact same model with the exact same hardware, it should. Maybe it is just being detected as a different one, or it IS different in some small way that is just enough to cause issues. Use the following commands to compare graphics cards detected in both laptops: 'lspci -vvnn | grep "VGA " ' Will show the card on the pci bus -- 'cat /var/log/dmesg | grep -i nvidia ' Shows the driver detected and used on boot

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today when I was installing Ubuntu on my new MSI GL62 laptop which has the NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960M graphics aswell. The issue, it turned out was not with the drivers as such but grub setting. I had 'nomodeset' and 'acpi=off' in grub to install ubuntu with the live CD. That setting got carried on to actual installation on my laptop. I think it's the 'nomodeset' that interferes with the NVIDIA graphics drivers and not the 'acpi'.

So I manually removed the options from `/etc/default/grub` and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, I don't have these settings in my grub file, any ideas ?